# Spark streaming persistent RDD partitions separation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a pyspark program that opens a direct stream to Kafka, reads messages and stores them on the disk. The program is running on a spark cluster, and the messages are saved locally on the disk of each client. The messages are stored in Kafka in a one-to-many key-value format, and I would like to separate the messages based on the keys (meaning that all the messages from a specific key will be stored only on a single spark client disk).

Currently the program is running successfully on the cluster, and the data is processed in parallel, but I am unable to get the requested behaviour.
I tried to reduce the data such that I am eventually handling a list of messages in parallel for each key, but when a new message with that key arrives, it may be handled by a different client (so eventually stored on a different machine than the other messages with that key).

I also thought to separate the messages to Kafka into partitions, since I know that spark creates a separate RDD partition for each Kafka partition, but I got the same result.

Is it possible to make RDD partitions separation persistent, or maybe get my requested behaviour in a different way?

I am using Kafka 0.9, Spark 1.6.1.

Thanks

Comment: its not very clear can you give one example.

Comment: yes, for example, let's say I have the following messages in Kafka:
1. key: A, value: ...
2. key: A, value: ...
3. key: B, value: ...
4. key: A, value: ...
If the first 3 messages are in the same batch, so I can make sure that both messages with key A are stored on the same client machine.
Then, if the 4th message is in another batch, I want to make sure it is stored on the same client machine as the first two messages (all have the same key A) but it may be processed by a worker on a different client - I can't save persistency between workers and batches..

Comment: ok, this seems to be more of design problem than technical. I am not aware of any such feature to save persistency. You can play with kafka offset here, each worker will realize its host-name and accordingly read and persist messages on the disk ignoring non-matching keys. Workers have to maintain their own offsets for reading from start of kafka topic. There can be other solutions too.